# Code in C to find largest and smallest numbers from text file

Tags: c

I am attempting to write a program that takes a user's inputted text file and returns the largest number, smallest number, average of the numbers and the standard deviation of the numbers. The text file that we input is formatted as such (with the first number being "N", or the total number of numbers, and the second row the list of all the numbers):

5

4.34 23.4 18.92 -78.3 17.9

So far, this is my code

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    double average, num = 0, min = 0, max = 0, sum = 0, N, std_dev, sum_sqs;
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("argv[1]", "r");
    fscanf(pFile, "%lf", &N);

    while(!feof(pFile))
    {
            fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num);
            if (num < min)
                    min = num;
            if (num > max)
                    max = num;
            sum += num;
            sum_sqs += (num*num);
    }
    average = sum/N;
    std_dev = sqrt((sum_sqs/N)-(average*average));

    printf("Smallest: %.2lf\n", min);
    printf("Largest: %.2lf\n", max);
    printf("Average: %.2lf\n)", average);
    printf("Standard deviation: %.3lf\n", std_dev);
return(0);
}
```

Currently, the compiler does not let me get past an error about an undefined reference to sqrt and i cannot figure out what's wrong. Thank you in advance to everybody who takes the time to respond! I really appreciate any help, I am still getting the hang of C. If my code is not doing what I intend it to do please dont hesitate to correct me!

Updated the messy part to below. Still not sure what exactly im doing with the rest though haha
    pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        fscanf(pFile, "%lf", &N);

```
    if (fscanf(pFile, "%lf", &N) == 1)
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
            if (fscanf(pFile, "%lf", &num) == 1)
                    if (num < min)
                            min = num;
                    if (num > max)
                            max = num;
                    sum += num;
                    sum_sqs += (num*num);
    }
    average = sum/N;
    std_dev = sqrt((sum_sqs/N)-(average*average));
```

Comment: You need to include the header file that contains sqrt and link with the library that implements it.  How to do the linking step depends on your compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Analysis

There is a wealth of problems in these few lines:

```
pFile = fopen("argv[1]", "r");
fscanf(pFile, "%lf", &N);

while(!feof(pFile))
{
        fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num);
```

1. You probably wanted to open the file designated by `argv[1]`, not a file called `argv[1]`.  Remove the quotes.
2. You didn't check that you were passed an argument.
3. You don't check that `fopen()` succeeded, so you probably crashed in your first `fscanf()`.
4. You don't check that `fscanf()` succeeded.  It is also odd to read what should probably be an integer value into a `double`, but the notation used will work.
5. You should not use `feof()` like that, especially if …
6. You don't check that the second `fscanf()` succeeded, and it won't work properly (but might not report the problem) because …
7. You are trying to read integers (`%d`) into a `double`.

So, you should have written:

```
if (argc <= 1)
    …report error and exit…(or use pFile = stdin)…
FILE *pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (pFile == 0)
    …report error and exit…
if (fscanf(pFile, "%lf", &N) == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (fscanf(pFile, "%lF", &num) != 1)
            …report error, close file, and exit…
        …as before…more or less…subject to fixing any as yet undiagnosed errors…
    }
}
fclose(pFile);
```

Incidentally, you forgot to set `sum_sqs` to zero before you started adding to it, so you won't know what value you got.  Also, if all the numbers are negative, you'll report that the maximum is 0; if all the numbers are positive, you'll report that the minimum is 0.  Fixing that is a tad fiddly, but you could use `if (i == 0 || num < min) min = num;` etc.

---

#### Linking Problem

Your linking problem (undefined reference to `sqrt()`) indicates that you are running on a system where you need to link the maths library; that is usually `-lm` on the end of the linking command line.

---

#### Synthesis

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    double average, num = 0, min = 0, max = 0, sum = 0, N, std_dev, sum_sqs = 0.0;

    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (pFile == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    if (fscanf(pFile, "%lf", &N) == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (fscanf(pFile, "%lF", &num) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to read number\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
            }

            if (num < min || i == 0)
                min = num;
            if (num > max || i == 0)
                max = num;
            sum += num;
            sum_sqs += (num*num);
        }
    }

    fclose(pFile);
    average = sum/N;
    std_dev = sqrt((sum_sqs/N)-(average*average));

    printf("Smallest: %7.2lf\n", min);
    printf("Largest: %7.2lf\n", max);
    printf("Average: %7.2lf\n", average);
    printf("Standard deviation: %7.3lf\n", std_dev);
    return(0);
}
```

#### Results

Given data file `data`:

```
5    
4.34 23.4 18.92 -78.3 17.9
```

The result of running the program is:

```
Smallest:  -78.30
Largest:   23.40
Average:   -2.75
Standard deviation:  38.309
```

Those values mostly look plausible; my calculation of the standard deviation came to 42.83 (using a different tool altogether).  The difference is between the sample standard deviation and the population standard deviation (a factor of √1.25) — so your value is OK as you calculated it.

```
# Count    = 5
# Sum(x1)  = -1.374000e+01
# Sum(x2)  =  7.375662e+03
# Mean     = -2.748000e+00
# Std Dev  =  4.283078e+01
# Variance =  1.834476e+03
# Min      = -7.830000e+01
# Max      =  2.340000e+01
```

So, the code works for me.  What result are you getting?

Comment: okay so if i switch it to what you input and then tack on the rest of what I had I switched a little but it still doesnt quite work. Any other suggestions? My code for the part in question looks like this

Comment: it works! thats exactly what i needed. thank you so much, seriously. you are the greatest

Comment: actually really quick. what is std-99 mode? it says i need to compile it that way

Comment: I used some features from the old C99 standard (instead of the almost archaic C89/C90 standard; and not anything solely in the new C11 standard). Specifically, I declared some variables part way through the function (not immediately at the top of a block), and I declared `i` in the `for` loop, rather than before hand.  You can easily move the declarations if you need to use C89; put `pFile` up at the top, and declare `i` just before the `for` loop instead of in the control clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `sqrt` function, you need to add

```
#include <math.h>
```

to the top of your C file.

- if you want to read a `float` with `scanf`, you should be using the `%f` format specifier, not `%d` (which will read an integer).
- In your `fopen` call, remove the quotes around `argv[1]`, otherwise it'll look for a file with that name.

Comment: Since the `<stdio.h>` is not shown either, we have to assume that both that and `<math.h>` were included.

Comment: yeah i forgot to include them in the copy/paste but both are included